Using nasm the stack grows after passing a label without explicitly approaching the stack
Why does the stack grow after passing a label in following code example? I haven't used any push instruction.
I need to trust the stack so I need granular control. I know my setup isn't conventional, that's on purpose.
If this is intended behaviour, is there a way around, so I can for example predict stack growth?
Makefile
test:
    nasm -g -F dwarf -felf64 test2.asm -o test.o
    ld -m elf_x86_64 --omagic test.o -o test

test2.asm
global _start

section .text
 
_start:
    xor     rax, rax
    xor     rbx, rbx
    mov     rsi, knitter
    mov     rdi, intermediary
test:
    mov     al, byte [rsi + rbx]
end:
    jmp     end

len_array equ 4096
intermediary: resb len_array

knitter:  db  "zend:", 10, \
              0   ; End of string

output gdb
(gdb) make -e test
make: 'test' is up to date.
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400080: file test2.asm, line 6.
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/nico/Dropbox/Projects/datalp/test

Breakpoint 2, _start () at test2.asm:6
6           xor     rax, rax
(gdb) n
7           xor     rbx, rbx
(gdb)
8           mov     rsi, knitter
(gdb) bt
#0  _start () at test2.asm:8
(gdb) n
9           mov     rdi, intermediary
(gdb) bt
#0  _start () at test2.asm:9
(gdb) n
test () at test2.asm:11
11          mov     al, byte [rsi + rbx]
(gdb) bt
#0  test () at test2.asm:11
#1  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffffffe8ee in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)


The stack didn't change. Gdb's interpretation of the stack changed.

Could you elaborate? Why is there a difference? You mean that if you add a 'pop r8' before end: you don't get 0x0000000000000001 in 'info reg r8' as in my example?

Assuming this is Linux, the top of the stack contains argc and argv upon entry to _start. So, yes, if you pop the stack you will get the value of argc. That is true before or after reaching the label "test".

I don't know why gdb displays the stack differently before and after the label. Clearly it is related to debugging information that it either gets from the binary or infers. My point is simply that the contents of the stack didn't change.

Just one more question, (I don't know who to address to, registering at the nasm forum takes already a week) does gas provide a predictable stack? I'm going to test for myself, but maybe you know. If gas isn't a valid alternative I probably go construct my own alternative written in binary instructions. It's a huge trade off, but a necessary initialization of my project.

Gas has nothing to do with the contents of the stack at the entry point _start. It is defined by the OS. It would be the same regardless of what tools you use.
